# How to Implement group chat bitween two or more channel through pubnub?

Tags: android, pubnub

I am implemented one to one chat through Pub nub.

For this I subscribe  channel and unsubscribe dynamically. It is working fine.

But my requirement is I want to create group of channels as a single group.Make chatting of these group.

If any one know how to do it. Please tell me the way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Channel Groups? https://www.pubnub.com/docs/java-se-java/api-reference#adding-channels